# failed to start Grid Manager Adapter in apache ignite

Tags: apache

This the program that I am running

```
    package IgniteCache.IgniteCache1;
   import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
 import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
  import org.junit.Test;

  public class HelloWorldCompute
  {
 public static void main(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException
{
{
    try(Ignite ignite=Ignition.start())
    {
        ignite.compute().broadcast(()->System.out.println("Hello World"));
    }
}
```

}
}

I am running the above code in my eclipse. after creating two nodes for apache ignite I am getting the following error in eclipse after running

```
  [16:41:16] (wrn) Default Spring XML file not found (is IGNITE_HOME set?): 
  config/default-config.xml
Oct 24, 2016 4:41:16 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
 SEVERE: Failed to resolve default logging config file:             
        config/java.util.logging.properties
[16:41:16]    __________  ________________ 
[16:41:16]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/ 
[16:41:16]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/   
[16:41:16] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/  
[16:41:16] 
[16:41:16] ver. 1.5.0-b1#20151202-sha1:062d440c
[16:41:16] 2015 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
[16:41:16] 
[16:41:16] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
[16:41:16] 
[16:41:16] Quiet mode.
[16:41:16]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false         or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
[16:41:16] 
[16:41:16] OS: Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
[16:41:16] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_92-b14          Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.92-b14
[16:41:16] Initial heap size is 128MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -      Xms512m -Xmx512m).
[16:41:17] Configured plugins:
[16:41:17]   ^-- None
[16:41:17] 
[16:41:17] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
  Oct 24, 2016 4:41:18 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
   SEVERE: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true,        name=o.a.i.i.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI:      TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, reconCnt=10,   maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false]
at        org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:255)
at    org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDis     coveryManager.java:660)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1500)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:915)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1618)
at        
  org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx
  .java:1485)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:965)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:494)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:470)
  at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:303)
            IgniteCache.IgniteCache1.HelloWorldCompute.main
                          (HelloWorldCompute.java:12)
   Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Local node and                remote node have different version numbers (node will not join, Ignite 
 does not support rolling updates, so versions must be exactly the same) [locBuildVer=1.7.0, rmtBuildVer=1.5.0-b1, locNodeAddrs=[gopi/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:1455:823d:82c1:2a3d/127.0.0.1, /172.17.7.70, /2001:0:9d38:6ab8:1455:823d:82c1:2a3d], rmtNodeAddrs=[gopi/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 
 gopi/127.0.0.1, /172.17.7.70, 
/2001:0:9d38:6ab8:1455:823d:82c1:2a3d], locNodeId=10922b26-14b0-4151-a503-           

  dca273e]
```

While in the command prompt I am getting the below error

```
   C:\apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin\bin>ignite.bat
       [17:57:10]    __________  ________________ 
       [17:57:10]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/
       [17:57:10]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/
        [17:57:10] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/
       [17:57:10]
       [17:57:10] ver. 1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3
     [17:57:10] 2016 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
    [17:57:10]
   [17:57:10] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
    [17:57:10]
  [17:57:10] Quiet mode.
 [17:57:10]   ^-- Logging to file 'C:\apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-    bin\work\log\ig
 ite-3f8aa05c.0.log'
       [17:57:10]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -          
    DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "
 v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
 [17:57:10]
     [17:57:10] OS: Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
   [17:57:10] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_92-b14   
        Oracle
  orporation Java HotSpot(TM)
 64-Bit Server VM 25.92-b14
[17:57:10] Configured plugins:
[17:57:10]   ^-- None
[17:57:10]
[17:57:10] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
[17:57:13] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.   
     {sh|bat}
 [17:57:13]
  [17:57:13] Ignite node started OK (id=3f8aa05c)
  [17:57:13] Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4,   
    heap=1.0GB]
    [17:57:42] Topology snapshot [ver=2, servers=2, clients=0, CPUs=4, 
      heap=2.0GB]
   [18:03:16,345][SEVERE][tcp-disco-multicast-addr-rcvr-#23%null%]   
    [TcpDiscoveryMul
   icastIpFinder] Failed to request nodes addresses.
    java.net.SocketException: bad argument for IP_MULTICAST_IF: address not   
      bound t
   any interface
     at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketNativeSetOption(Nati
   e Method)
      at      
     java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketSetOption(TwoStacksP
    ainDatagramSocketImpl.java:146)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.setOption(AbstractPlainData
     ramSocketImpl.java:309)
      at java.net.MulticastSocket.setInterface(MulticastSocket.java:471)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryM
       lticastIpFinder.requestAddresses(TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder
   .java:547)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryM
   lticastIpFinder.access$700(TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder.java:80)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryM

           lticastIpFinder$AddressReceiver.body
   (TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder.java:758)


   at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.checkFailedError
   (TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1627)
   at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology 
   (ServerImpl.java:879)
  at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart
  (ServerImpl.java:328)
  at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart
  (TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1815)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter
 .startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:252)
... 10 more

  Oct 24, 2016 4:41:18 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
 SEVERE: Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
 class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager:    
  GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true,    
       name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery
 .GridDiscoveryManager]
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager
  (IgniteKernal.java:1505)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:915)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.
     start0(IgnitionEx.java:1618)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start
  (IgnitionEx.java:1485)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:965)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:494)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:470)
   at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:303)
   at IgniteCache.IgniteCache1.HelloWorldCompute
  .main(HelloWorldCompute.java:12)
 Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: 
 Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000,           
    ackTimeout=5000, reconCnt=10, maxAckTimeout=600000,
 forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter
.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:255)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.
 GridDiscoveryManager.start
 (GridDiscoveryManager.java:660)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager
 (IgniteKernal.java:1500)
   ... 8 more
  Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException
 : Local node and remote node have different version numbers (node will not          
   join, Ignite does not support rolling updates, so versions 
  must be exactly the same) [locBuildVer=1.7.0, rmtBuildVer=1.5.0-b1,    
   locNodeAddrs=[gopi/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,      
     2001:0:9d38:6ab8:1455:823d:82c1:2a3d/127.0.0.1,
  /172.17.7.70, /2001:0:9d38:6ab8:1455:823d:82c1:2a3d], rmtNodeAddrs=  
  [gopi/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, gopi/127.0.0.1, /172.17.7.70,  
 /2001:0:9d38:6ab8:1455:823d:82c1:2a3d], locNodeId=10922b26-14b0-4151-a503-
     75e83c241278, rmtNodeId=edfc9197-3d0b-4d19-bd8a-94a93dca273e]
```

I am using windows 8.1 and my firewall is off no antivirus..

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
            1)Because ignite services are running with different configuration files in same server(it may be one reason)
```

#

```
            service 1)   [stp@ril-srv-sp4 bin]$ ./ignite.sh "/home/stp/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/examples/config/example-cache.xml"
            service 2)   [stp@ril-srv-sp4 bin]$ ./ignite.sh "/home/stp/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/examples/config/example-ignite.xml"
```

#

#terminal 1

```
            [stp@ril-srv-sp4 bin]$ ./ignite.sh "/home/stp/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/examples/config/example-cache.xml"
            OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
            [15:17:55]    __________  ________________ 
            [15:17:55]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/
            [15:17:55]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/
            [15:17:55] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/
            [15:17:55]
            [15:17:55] ver. 1.5.0-b1#20151202-sha1:062d440c
            [15:17:55] 2015 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
            [15:17:55]
            [15:17:55] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
            [15:17:55]
            [15:17:55] Quiet mode.
            [15:17:55]   ^-- Logging to file '/home/stp/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/work/log/ignite-5fa97ab6.0.log'
            [15:17:55]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
            [15:17:55]
            [15:17:55] OS: Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 amd64
            [15:17:55] VM information: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_102-b14 Oracle Corporation OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.102-b14
            [15:17:55] Configured plugins:
            [15:17:55]   ^-- None
            [15:17:55]
            [15:17:55] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
            [15:17:57] Performance suggestions for grid  (fix if possible)
            [15:17:57] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
            [15:17:57]   ^-- Decrease number of backups (set 'keyBackups' to 0)
            [15:17:57]
            [15:17:57] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
            [15:17:57]
            [15:17:57] Ignite node started OK (id=5fa97ab6)
            [15:17:57] Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=1.0GB]
            [15:18:06] New version is available at ignite.apache.org: 1.7.0
            [15:18:10] Topology snapshot [ver=2, servers=2, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=2.0GB]
            [15:18:11] Topology snapshot [ver=3, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=1.0GB]
```

########################terminal 2

#

```
            [stp@ril-srv-sp4 bin]$ ./ignite.sh "/home/stp/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/examples/config/example-ignite.xml"
            OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
            [15:18:08]    __________  ________________
            [15:18:08]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/
            [15:18:08]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/
            [15:18:08] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/
            [15:18:08]
            [15:18:08] ver. 1.5.0-b1#20151202-sha1:062d440c
            [15:18:08] 2015 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
            [15:18:08]
            [15:18:08] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
            [15:18:08]
            [15:18:08] Quiet mode.
            [15:18:08]   ^-- Logging to file '/home/stp/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/work/log/ignite-feae7ff1.0.log'
            [15:18:08]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
            [15:18:08]
            [15:18:08] OS: Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 amd64
            [15:18:08] VM information: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_102-b14 Oracle Corporation OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.102-b14
            [15:18:08] Configured plugins:
            [15:18:08]   ^-- None
            [15:18:08]
            [15:18:09] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
            [15:18:10,964][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal] Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=o.a.i.i.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
            class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Remote node has peer class loading enabled flag different from local [locId8=feae7ff1, locPeerClassLoading=true, rmtId8=5fa97ab6, rmtPeerClassLoading=false, rmtAddrs=[ril-srv-sp4/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1, /192.168.1.14]]
```

2)
                Exception getting in second Service ,if we use common config files for two services it will work

```
            service 1)   [stp@ril-srv-sp4 bin]$ ./ignite.sh "/home/stp/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/examples/config/example-cache.xml"
            service 2)   [stp@ril-srv-sp4 bin]$ ./ignite.sh "/home/stp/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/examples/config/example-cache.xml"
```

###########################terminal 1

```
            [stp@ril-srv-sp4 bin]$ ./ignite.sh "/home/stp/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/examples/config/example-cache.xml"
            OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
            [15:25:41]    __________  ________________
            [15:25:41]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/
            [15:25:41]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/
            [15:25:41] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/
            [15:25:41]
            [15:25:41] ver. 1.5.0-b1#20151202-sha1:062d440c
            [15:25:41] 2015 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
            [15:25:41]
            [15:25:41] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
            [15:25:41]
            [15:25:41] Quiet mode.
            [15:25:41]   ^-- Logging to file '/home/stp/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/work/log/ignite-ed543f4a.0.log'
            [15:25:41]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
            [15:25:41]
            [15:25:41] OS: Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 amd64
            [15:25:41] VM information: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_102-b14 Oracle Corporation OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.102-b14
            [15:25:41] Configured plugins:
            [15:25:41]   ^-- None
            [15:25:41]
            [15:25:41] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
            [15:25:43] Performance suggestions for grid  (fix if possible)
            [15:25:43] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
            [15:25:43]   ^-- Decrease number of backups (set 'keyBackups' to 0)
            [15:25:43]
            [15:25:43] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
            [15:25:43]
            [15:25:43] Ignite node started OK (id=ed543f4a)
            [15:25:43] Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=1.0GB]
            [15:25:52] New version is available at ignite.apache.org: 1.7.0
            [15:25:58] Topology snapshot [ver=2, servers=2, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=2.0GB]
```

###########################termainal 2

```
            [stp@ril-srv-sp4 bin]$ ./ignite.sh "/home/stp/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/examples/config/example-cache.xml"
            OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
            [15:25:56]    __________  ________________
            [15:25:56]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/
            [15:25:56]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/
            [15:25:56] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/
            [15:25:56]
            [15:25:56] ver. 1.5.0-b1#20151202-sha1:062d440c
            [15:25:56] 2015 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
            [15:25:56]
            [15:25:56] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
            [15:25:56]
            [15:25:56] Quiet mode.
            [15:25:56]   ^-- Logging to file '/home/stp/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/work/log/ignite-169dab96.0.log'
            [15:25:56]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
            [15:25:56]
            [15:25:56] OS: Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 amd64
            [15:25:56] VM information: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_102-b14 Oracle Corporation OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.102-b14
            [15:25:56] Configured plugins:
            [15:25:56]   ^-- None
            [15:25:56]
            [15:25:56] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
            [15:25:59] Performance suggestions for grid  (fix if possible)
            [15:25:59] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
            [15:25:59]   ^-- Decrease number of backups (set 'keyBackups' to 0)
            [15:25:59]
            [15:25:59] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
            [15:25:59]
            [15:25:59] Ignite node started OK (id=169dab96)
            [15:25:59] Topology snapshot [ver=2, servers=2, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=2.0GB]
            [15:26:06] New version is available at ignite.apache.org: 1.7.0
            [15:27:13] Topology snapshot [ver=3, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=1.0GB]
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code answers, also provide some commentary on what your code is doing.

Comment: can anyone explain the answer in a consolidated format. thanks in advance